# What is the correct syntax to add no_cache to a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to specify a container should **not** use cache when docker builds the container.  Support for the `--no-cache` command-line argument was added in [docker-compose 2.4.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#240).  This works fine for me, no trouble at all.

It is also listed in the [official compose file build reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#no_cache), see [types.go line 313](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/types/types.go#L313) and [compose-spec.json, line 98](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/schema/compose-spec.json#L98).

However, when I try to add any variation of `no_cache: true` under my `compose.yaml` `build:` stanza, I get the following error:

`ERROR: The Compose file '/opt/docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because: services.pleroma.build contains unsupported option: 'no_cache'`

Am I using incorrect syntax here, or is this simply not possible to currently do **in the compose file itself?**  Below is the entire config for the image I want to build.

```
  pleroma:
    image: pleroma
    hostname: pleroma
    container_name: pleroma
    networks:
      dockerapps:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.77
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:4000 || exit 1",
        ]
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: /opt/pleroma/.
      dockerfile: /opt/pleroma/Dockerfile
      no_cache: true
      # Feel free to remove or override this section
      # See 'Build-time variables' in README.md
      args:
        - "UID=1000"
        - "GID=1000"
        - "PLEROMA_VER=develop"
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/var/lib/pleroma/uploads
      - ./static:/var/lib/pleroma/static
      - ./config.exs:/etc/pleroma/config.exs:ro
      - ./config-override.exs:/var/lib/pleroma/config.exs:ro
    env_file:
      - /opt/pleroma/.docker.env
    depends_on:
      - pleroma_db
```

Comment: Are you using `docker-compose` or `docker compose`? And what version?

Comment: @HansKilian docker-compose, version 1.28.2, build 67630359

Comment: I don't think docker-compose (with the hyphen) supports it. The 'no_cache' tag is only in the 'docker compose' docs. Docker compose is the version that comes with Docker Desktop and yes, it's a damn nightmare with the two versions :(

Comment: The Compose file formats that Docker labels as "legacy" work consistently across all Compose implementations in current widespread use, and neither [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#build) nor [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) support `build: { no_cache: }`.

Comment: (I'm also surprised you think you need to hard-code this on – usually the default behavior is fine, where the cache is invalidated only if a file you `COPY` into the image changes.  Are you okay removing this option entirely?)